# Comparing LED monitor image sharpness and quality without physically putting them side-by-side

Tags: display

I'd like to compare the image quality of two monitors, the HP W2071d I'm using and the LG E1941 my family is using. We're living in different continents so there's no way to put them next to each other. I recalled the LG was sharper when I used it in my last visit (and could especially feel this when I came back and resumed using the HP again), but now my memory of the LG monitor has faded.

Is there any way I can somehow compare the image quality of the two? Anything (screenshots, movie etc) sent from one party will necessarily be rendered on the other party's monitor, and so a direct comparison seems impossible. I have a spare laptop computer, if that is useful.

Comment: Outside of DPI (and maybe screen coatings), I wonder what would make one LCD monitor sharper than another.

Comment: I'm not sure if I used the correct word, but what my impression about the HP monitor is that the images are a bit dull, while the same picture (or when gaming) is much more vivid on the LG monitor. The HP monitor is by no means bad though, but it does feel inferior. Now that I've little memory about the LG I would like to find a way to compare them.

Comment: I have experienced the same thing.  I think it may be due to color saturation, but I'm not sure.  I have tried adjusting the saturation, but it does not achieve the desired vivid, yet natural, appearance.

Comment: Yeah.. I've tried everything I could on the HP too. There must be some intrinsic differences that result in this.